# Volt compiled filenames can get very long and fail creation on Windows

Tags: windows, filenames, phalcon, volt

Volt compiled files can become very long depending on the depth of the folder structure that the web server or developer has. In Windows environments this can exceed the 255 limit and as a result the files are not being saved.

Example:

`%%users%%john%%documents%%htdocs%%projects%%clients%%awesomecorp%%sandbox%%revolutionaryapp%%integrations%%app%%portal%%app%%views%%index%%index.php`

A solution would be to store the file as a hash (md5/sha1) and thus circumventing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NFR has been created for this [#3226](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/3226), to be addressed after 2.0 is released. However there is an easy workaround as @[Andres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1022921/twistedxtra) offers

You can currently use a closure to generate this kind of file:

```
$volt->setOptions(
    [
        'compiledPath' => function($templatePath) {
            return md5($templatePath) . '.php';
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: This way the compiled file would be stored in the same folder as the original template file. What about storing compiled files with hashed filenames in a separate the app/cache/volt folder?

Comment: @ГеоргиБанков just change the return statement `return 'app/cache/volt/' . md5($templatePath) . '.php';`